# Linux: concatenate several images into a PDF file with several images per page

Tags: linux, images, conversion, imagemagick

I know that ImageMagick's `convert` program can be used as follows to convert a collection of images -- say, in PNG format -- to a PDF file:

```
convert *png output.pdf
```

The problem with this is that each image is then stretched to fit on one page, whereas I would like to keep the original dimensions of the images and put as many as possible on one page in the PDF file before moving on to another page.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do, placing many images in one (PDF) page, is not trivial. Even the notion of "original dimension" of an image is no longer trivial, once something like PDF is involved. The dimension of an image is given in pixels, while PDFs have no idea about pixels. You have to mess around with stuff like dpi (dots per inch, or pixels per inch).

I suggest you look up some typsetting tools, like [LaTeX](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX).

Comment: Great idea, I just tried it although I was unsure it would be suitable, as I'm interested in automating the generation of the document and was afraid I would have to play around with various parameters, but it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to LaTeX, you could combine the usage of [imagemagick's `montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#concatenate) to generate each page and then concatenate the resulting montages into a multi-page PDF.

The actual commands to run will depend on how variable the size of images is.